# TFS 2015 - Public View of Backlog Board

Tags: tfs-2015

Is there any way to set up a public view (View Only) of the Product Backlog Board for the customer see what we are working on and so?

It would be awesome too, if the customer could vote for backlog item that we haven't start working on it.

Trying to get the same concept of https://trello.com/ in TFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing (View Only) of the Product Backlog Board for the customer is easy to achieve. You just need to set related permissions for your customer or customer group.

Such as assign the user stakeholder access which have permission  to view backlogs.

> Assign Stakeholder access to those users who need to enter bugs, view
>   backlogs, boards, charts, and dashboards, but who don't have a TFS
>   CAL. Stakeholder access is free. Stakeholders can also view releases
>   and manage release approvals. See Stakeholder access for details of
>   features available to stakeholders.
>
> Source Link: [Change access levels](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/change-access-levels)

Then you need to deny some permissions which you don't want custom to have.

As for the second  thing, there is no this kind of feature in TFS for now. Even though  you have ability to prioritise Backlog items by dragging and dropping the item. If you need this feature, you can sumbit a feature requst in [uservoice stie](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services), TFS Admin and PM will kindly reveiw your suggestion.